# Symfony doesn't authenticate users

Tags: php, symfony, oauth, fosuserbundle

I have a Symfony 2.8 web app made like an API with FosUserBundle for users entities and Fosoauthserver for authentication.

My security.yml is this:

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

firewalls:
    oauth_token:
        pattern:    ^/oauth/v2/token
        security:   false

    oauth_authorize:
        pattern:    ^/oauth/v2/auth
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            check_path: /oauth/v2/auth_login_check
            login_path: /oauth/v2/auth_login
        anonymous: true

    api:
        pattern:    ^/v1
        fos_oauth:  true
        stateless:  true
        switch_user_stateless: true
        anonymous:  false

access_control:
    - { path: ^/v1/register, role:  IS_AUTHENTICAIS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY  }
    - { path: ^/v1/login, role:  IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY  }
    - { path: ^/v1, role:  IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY  }
```

I can register an user and login, getting the access_token correctly, but when I try to access to any end point of my API I can access without login.

Even, if I set the right Access token in the headers, if I do $this->getUser() I get null because in any point my app is doing the authentication check.

Any idea? I made differente APIs and never I had this problem.
Thanks!